# Compiling old 1.4 java code in java 1.6 using ANT

Tags: java, ant

Hi I am trying to compile old java project in 1.6 java version using ant but i am getting following errors.

```
>  package com.sun.rsasign does not exist
>     [javac] import com.sun.rsasign.t;
> 
>         
>         cannot find symbol
>         [javac] symbol  : class Base64Encoder
>         [javac] location: package base64
>         [javac] import base64.Base64Encoder;
>     cannot find symbol
>         [javac] symbol  : variable Base64Encoder
```

Could you please help me to resolve issue?
Also please not that i am building two different project using same ANT build one is based on 1.6 JAVA and this is based on 1.4 JAVA.
I am able to compile 1.6 JAVA project but stuck in 1.4 JAVA project compilation.

Comment: The project uses internal sun API. It may be gone now. Even if you manage to compile it, you will need old Java to run it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the problem with versions during compilation. It is due to the missing packages. Classpath doesn't have `com.sun.rasign` package and `Base64Encoder` class file

Note : When you try to compile Java 1.4 source with Java 1.6 compiler. You may get into problems when any changes have been made to the Java API.

See @Leos Literak comment, very useful one.

Comment: Yes i know but how to fix this now? i am getting 3 errors for Base64Encoder and rasign , i guess this was included in 1.4 and now its deprecated / not included in 1.6

Comment: Use apache-commons codec for Base64Encoder and update your code

Comment: I downloaded & used apache common codec 1.9 but still same issue...not working :(

Comment: You have to modify source code and rewrite it to use the  other implementation.

Comment: @user3134221 You have to rewrite the code again to make it work on Java 1.6

Comment: what about this issue? package com.sun.rsasign does not exist

Comment: @user3134221 as said by Leo, the above package would have been gone now.

Comment: If you are compiling, you have source codes and then it is possible (maybe not allowed) to modify them. If your company wants you to compile it then it shall allow you to fix this bug. Yes, it is bug cause com.sun.* packages were Java internal and it was prohibited to use them by ordinal developers.